# How to create a web service in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, ajax, sitecore

There is a tabbed panel like HTML in the page, where each tab click will show different data. 
Trying to accomplish this with Ajax calls.
In the Visual studio project, I created a web service **test.asmx**, inside **Services** folder. So on publish, it is saved at `wwwroot/MyApp/Website/Services/test.asmx`

**asmx.cs**

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class test : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
```

**ascx**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="_scriptManager" runat="server">
  <Services>
    <asp:ServiceReference Path="/Services/test.asmx" />
  </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {     
        console.log("howdy");  //this does print   
        var Param1 = 'one';
        var Param2 = 'two';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Services/test.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data:"",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: "true",
            cache: "false",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            },
            Error: function (x, e) {
                alert("errrrr");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

On browsing the page, there is this error in the browser console.

> GET http://MyApp/Services/test.asmx/HelloWorld 500 (Internal Server
>   Error) jQuery.noconflict.js:16

1. Is this the right way to make the call
2. Is it because of the prototype.js conflict (not again !!). I already said `jQuery(function ($) {`..., but still.....

Answer (score 4):

Personally I wouldn't use a web service because I dont think you are going to have the right Sitecore context for doing Sitecore work. I would just use MVC route and use it like an web api.

The controller

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Bonfire.Kickfire.Analytics.Dto;
using Bonfire.Kickfire.Analytics.Models;

namespace Bonfire.Kickfire.Analytics.Controllers
{
    public class VisitorController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult VisitorDetailsJson()
        {
            var item = Sitecore.Context.Item;
            var vi = new VisitorInformation();
            var trackerDto2 = vi.GetTrackerDto();

            return Json(trackerDto2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }        
    }
}
```

The route

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;

namespace Bonfire.Kickfire.Analytics.Pipelines.Initialize
{
    public class InitRoutes : Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes
    {
        public override void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
                "Profile", // Route name
                "VisitorData", // URL with parameters
                new {controller = "Visitor", action = "VisitorDetailsJSON"},
                new[] {"Bonfire.Kickfire.Analytics.Controllers"});
        }
    }
}
```

The patch file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Bonfire.Kickfire.Analytics.Pipelines.Initialize.InitRoutes, Bonfire.Kickfire.Analytics"
          patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']"/>
      </initialize>
      </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```